# ConstraintViolationException JPA

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

I'm trying to add some data to database using JPA entity with @SequenceGenerator. But appears that this genereator doesnt do what it is expected to do and i have no clue why.

```
Hibernate: call next value for seq1
Hibernate: insert into Customer (FirstName, Surname, code, customerType, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
13:20:36,078 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10093 table: CUSTOMER column: FIRST_NAME
```

Heres my model class :

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "seq1", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
private Long id;

public String FirstName;
public String Surname;
public String code;
public enum Customertype{Private, Corporate};
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Customertype customerType;
```

Servlet where i call my save method

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    new SqlExecutor().execute("/schema.sql");

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setFirstName("Peeter");
    new CustomerDAO().save(customer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the generator. The error message is extremely clear:

> NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10093 table: CUSTOMER column: FIRST_NAME

So, you're trying to insert a row in the customer table, which has a not null column named FIRST_NAME, and for which no value is provided. So you get a constraint violation exception.

The SQL statement is

```
insert into Customer (FirstName, Surname, code, customerType, id)
```

so, you see, there is no value inserted for FIRST_NAME.

That also shows that your table has a column named FirstName, and another one named FIRST_NAME. That's really not a good idea.

Comment: Is it better to change entity property names like they are in schema file or is it better to add @COLUMN annotations there? THanks :)

Comment: Java property names should respect the standard Java naming conventions. column names should respect your database naming conventions. If the conventions don't match, `@Column` allows specifying the column name associated to a property.

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation @Column with specified column name to field FirstName:

```
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
public String FirstName;
```

For more info try to look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes